# Code for time derivative or time differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I have three variables $X, Y, Z$ whose functional form is the following (I also have a function for $Z$ which is somewhat complicated but is not essential for my question here; so it is omitted.):

$X=a+bY$

$\dot{Y}=c+dZ$

where $a,b,c,d$ are abstract parameters, and the overdot refers to time derivative of the variable, i.e. $\frac{dY}{dt}$.

Setting aside an obvious fact that this system is reduced to $\dot{X}=\dot{Z}$, I would like to know the Mathematica code for this system. For the first equation, I have

```
X[Y_] := a + b*Y
```

But I am stuck with the second one. Do I have to make the variables a function of time `t`? But in that case, doesn't the system become discrete, not continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, make `X`, `Y`, and `Z` functions of `t`.  And use `Equal` instead of `Set` or `SetDelayed`.

Example with `Z[t] = Exp[t]`:

```
Block[{Z = Exp},
 DSolve[{X[t] == a + b Y[t], Y'[t] == c + d Z[t]}, {X[t], Y[t]}, t]
 ]
(*  {{X[t] -> a + b (d E^t + c t + C[1]), Y[t] -> d E^t + c t + C[1]}}  *)
```

Comment: thank you so much! Question: Why can we not include `Z` function into the `DSolve` bracket and instead use `Block`?

Comment: @ppp You're welcome.  The `C[1]` is a constant of integration generated automatically by `DSolve`; if you add an initial condition for `Y`, `C[1]` will be replaced by a value.  You can use an arbitrary `Z`: `DSolve[{X[t] == a + b Y[t], Y'[t] == c + d Z[t]}, {X[t], Y[t]}, t]` works as is.  You said you had a function for `Z`, so I gave an example with a function for `Z`. :)

Comment: @ppp Oops, I think I misunderstood your Q about `Z`.  Of course you can substitute an expression for `Z[t]`.  Your Q was in terms of `Z`, so I wanted to give an answer in terms of `Z`.

Comment: I tried `DSolve[{X[t] == a + b Y[t], Y'[t] == c + d Z[t], Z[t] == Exp[t]}, {X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}, t]` and it says `E^t cannot be used as a function`. Many thanks :)

Comment: @ppp I get `{{X[t] -> a + b (d E^t + c t + C[1]), Y[t] -> d E^t + c t + C[1], Z[t] -> E^t}}`.  (V10.0.1.)

Comment: @ Michael E2 It worked! Can I ask one last question? What if I have many equations, not just two. In such case, any easier way than to include all those equations into `DSolve` bracket? I really appreciate :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17560/discussion-between-michael-e2-and-ppp).